# How to store JSON array to dynamic List<>?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm just curious if there's a way to store JSON Array to dynamic List<> ?

For example :

Here's my JSON Array :

> [ { "trx_id": 1, "bank_id": 50 } ]

I want to assign those JSON Array to a new **List**<>. Here's my code :

```
var dynObjectsList = new List<dynamic>(); // I want to assign both properties name and properties value to this variable
```

Here's the reason why i want it this way :

Basically, I'm building a client API to consume a web service. Let's say I successfully consumed **web service A** and **web service B**. I need to store the value returned from **web service A** and **web service B** in a **separated** **List<>**, so I can use **Linq** for **JOIN-ing** the **List<>**. I can store it easily if I got the **model** for each **web service**, but unfortunately I don't have it, so I need to build the **List<>** manually

I've been gooling it for awhile, but no luck for me.

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: could you please explain why do you need JSON Array as a dynamic variable ?

Comment: hi @Vladimir, see my edited post above , thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using newtonsoft.json nuget package you could do the following:

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>("[{ \"trx_id\": 1, \"bank_id\": 50 }]");
```

Comment: Man, thanks so much, I didn't expect it that way, so many distraction in my head @_@. Thanks dude